# How do I create a Postgres subselect using prisma?

Tags: typescript, prisma

I have 3 database connections on Prisma Clients:

```js
const prisma = new PrismaClient();
const portal = new PORTAL();
const portal2 = new PORTAL2();
```

Schema file:

```
//prisma
model Computer {
  sector_id Int
  employee_id Int

  sector Int
  employee String
}

//portal
model Sector {
  cod_cost_center Int      @id
  description     String?  @db.VarChar(100)
  status          Boolean?
  classification  Int?

}

//portal2
model Employee {
  id       Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  name     String     
  email    String     
  phone    String     
  status   Boolean    @default(true)
  
  
}
```

And I'm trying to make a kind of subselect this way (but there's an error message saying that it `" is not assignable to type 'ComputerInclude' "`:

```js
const employees = await portal.registration.findMany({
        where: {
          cod_pj: 1,
          status: true,
        },

        select: {
          value: true,
          person: {
            select: {
              name: true,
            },
          },
        },
      });

const sectors = await portal2.cost_center.findMany({
        where: {
          status: true,
        },
        orderBy: {
          cod_cost_center: "asc",
        },
      });

const computers = await prisma.computer.findMany({
        include: {
          sectors: {
            select: {
              cod_cost_center: true,
              name: true,
            },
          },
          employees: {
            select: {
              value: true, 
              person: {
                select: {
                  name: true,
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      });
```

Basically, I want to include the return of **sectors** and **employees** on my prisma.computer.findMany({}). Is it possible?

I think there's no way to make relations using prisma on these tables because they are in different databases.

Comment: Can you share your schema file?

Comment: sure, added more info :)

Comment: I tried using

```const computers = await prisma.computer.findMany({
        include: {
          ...employees,
          ...sectors,...

It is acceptable, but now I have another error:

```Unknown field `0` for include statement on model Computer. Available options are listed in green.
Unknown field `1` for include statement on model Computer. Available options are listed in green. 


...
```

And this is for each element I have on ```Employees```

Answer (score 1):

Prisma doesn't allow subselect natively as of now.

There is a [Feature Request](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/6506) to support the same.

As of now using [queryRaw](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access#queryraw) through Raw Database access should allow you to achieve it.